# Magneto2 : What are the Tables effected when an order created

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, php-7

I am creating custom attributes and magento 2.2.6 and I just want the list of the tables effected after an order creates successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sales_order` the main order entity table

`sales_order_item` contains the order items (one entry or two entries for each order line, two for example for configurable products)

`sales_order_address` contains the addresses of an order (one entry for billing and one for shipping)

`sales_order_payment` contains payment realated data

`sales_order_grid` contains data which is used in the grid view in backend

`sales_order_tax` and `sales_order_tax_item` contains tax information about applied tax rates

There are some more involved tables like `quote` or the customer tables where data is updated depending on what happens in the order (e.g. a customer registres during checkout)

There are also some more tables implied for invoice creation (depending on your payment an invoice may be created directly) or credit memos.